# How to type an object with optional and default values?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've an old JavaScript (`.js`) file with a function like so:

```js
export default ({
  guid,
  numItems,
  lastDate,
  filters = [],
  includeCart = true,
  fetchStuff = true,
  withLove = true
}) => () => {
  // do stuff
}
```

As you can see, the entries in the argument object is getting long so I'd like convert the file to TypeScript (`.ts`) and put some constraints around this argument object.

I'd want to do something like this:

```
interface IPayload {
   guid: string
   numItems: number
   lastDate: string
   filters: string[]
   includeCart?: boolean
   fetchStuff?: boolean
   withLove?: boolean
}

export default (payload: IPayload) => () => { // do stuff }
```

However, since the argument supplies default values into the function, if I create a TypeScript interface, I can't supply default values. So, if the old function had a statement like:

```
if (includeCart) { // include the cart }
```

if the property isn't supplied, it would always default to true but in my refactor, it would be undefined thereby changing the behavior of this function.

How would I properly refactor this bit of function in order to make it more kosher in the TypeScript world?

Answer (score 1):

You could list the parameters with default values explicitely and use the spread operator to get the rest of the properties in a seperate variable.

```
const fn = ({ 
    filters = [], 
    fetchStuff = true, 
    withLove = true, 
    ...payload 
  }: IPayload) => { 
  console.log(filters, fetchStuff, withLove, payload)
}

fn({ guid: "", numItems: 0, lastDate: "", filters: [] })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU4E8A2B7OAE2QG8AoZSgcwFdhCAuZAZzClCospBoFtVIvZkx68ARtC7IccVgBE4kJq3YhOlZDGA5IUYSzYcA2gF0poBDhqEIAYThQwAfiZi8eHBDggpMCGAQACwBlMBoYGBdkNw8vHw0Ad2AwQIAZPAA3CCiYz28yAF8yMgQ8EFZNEGQAXmQAChJNbV1mGuRTABpNfyDQ8Jg2thoILqSU9KzBqGGugDp5gAdsfCJkAqYMZYJCAEoagD5SZC5S8tjZ-Co6rR1oZi6-AJCwiNHktMyR5CXcbZ3C4owEANZC0ehMABEEK6ogEECETAADF0ZPJFBBIdCmrc9ExTGsdkA)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a typed argument object with individual properties default values, using destructuring as in the original JS version:

```
interface IPayload {
  guid: string
  numItems: number
  lastDate: string
  filters: string[] // Should be optional as well BTW?
  includeCart?: boolean
  fetchStuff?: boolean
  withLove?: boolean
}

export default ({
  guid,
  numItems,
  lastDate,
  filters = [],
  includeCart = true
  fetchStuff = true
  withLove = true
}: IPayload) => () => { // do stuff }
```